# Angular syntax not working after upgrading to Angular 1.3.20

Tags: angularjs

Recently we have updated our application to angular 1.3.20 version. But after the upgradation the existing code is throwing angular error.

```
app.controller('searchController', ['$scope','TemplateViewService','$http','SearchService','$browser','$rootScope','$state','$location', '$uibModal','ReadConfigurationService','$filter','SpinnerService','$log', function($scope,TemplateViewService,$http,SearchService,$browser,$rootScope,$state,$location, $uibModal,ReadConfigurationService,$filter,SpinnerService,$log){//PA1501-1206
            var productType = undefined;
            //PA1501-2173 start
            $scope.dataList = SearchService.getDataList();  
            $scope.dataListCopy = SearchService.getDataListCopy();
            $scope.deleteList = [];
            $scope.displayArtifactList=[];
};
```

Here at this line I am getting Angular Js error Unknown provider TemplateViewService <- searchController.

Can anyone please suggest, how to resolve this error.

Comment: do you have a service named `TemplateViewService` and included that file in your index.html?

Comment: are you including TemplateViewService js file is this file loading successfully?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of TemplateViewService js file is not getting compiler, please make sure it again....